# Find all keys expiring within next X hours

Tags: redis, ttl

Is there a way to fetch all keys who are about to expire within the next X hours?

I see that the [scan method](https://redis.io/commands/scan) only seem to pattern match, and I can't seem to find any other commands which lets me do this.

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not provide this capability (yet). You can, however, keep a Sorted Set where the elements are the key names and the scores are their expiry timestamp - this will allow you to query (`ZRANGEBYSCORE`) as you wish, at the price of maintaining that data structure.

Comment: I see. This is a great idea, but we are not going to need a permanent solution. We cached some data by mistake and would have liked to do a batch-job and clear it out, but the issue was not very big, so we simply waited for it to resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK not possible without a full scan of keys. There is no command or group of commands which can provide that information.
`KEYS` combined with `TTL` or `PTTL` may be the only option, but requires full scan. Redis `pipeline` will improve the performance.

Comment: How would I implement this?